# What would break if the C locale was UTF-8 instead of ASCII?

Tags: character-encoding, locale, posix, unicode, compatibility

The C locale is defined to use the ASCII charset and POSIX does not provide a way to use a charset without changing the locale as well.

What would happen if the encoding of C were switched to UTF-8 instead?

The positive side would be that UTF-8 would become the default charset for any process, even system daemons. Obviously there would be applications that would break because they assume that C uses 7-bit ASCII. But do these applications really exist? Right now a lot of written code is locale- and charset-aware to a certain extent, I would be surprised to see code that can *only* deal with 7-bit clean input and cannot be easily adapted to accept a UTF-8-enabled C.

Comment: [This thread from 2009](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2009-09/msg00042.html) discusses the need for an UTF-8-based C locale, but does not address the problem of breaking POSIX.

Comment: FWIW, OpenBSD has a `C.UTF-8` locale, as well as `POSIX.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C locale is not the default locale. It is a locale that is guaranteed not to cause any “surprising” behavior. A number of commands have output of a guaranteed form (e.g. `ps` or `df` headers, `date` format) in the `C` or `POSIX` locale. For encodings (`LC_CTYPE`), it is guaranteed that `[:alpha:]` only contains the ASCII letters, and so on. If the `C` locale was modified, this would call many applications to misbehave. For example, they might reject input that is invalid UTF-8 instead of treating it as binary data.

If you want all programs on your system to use UTF-8, set the default locale to UTF-8. All programs that manipulate a single encoding, that is. Some programs only manipulate byte streams and don't care about encodings. Some programs manipulate multiple encodings and don't care about the locale (for example, a web server or web client sets or reads the encoding for each connection in a header).

Answer (score 6):

You are a bit confused, I think.  The "C locale" is a locale like any other, which, as you point out, is conventionally a synonym for 7-bit ASCII.

It's built into the C library, I suppose so that the library has some kind of fallback -- there can't be no locale.

However, this does not have anything to do with the how programs built from C code deal with input.  The locale is used to translate input that is handed *to* an executable, which if the system locale is UTF-8, UTF-8 is what the program gets regardless of whether its source was written in C or something else.  So:

> I would be surprised to see code that can only deal with 7-bit clean
>   input and cannot be easily adapted to accept a UTF-8-enabled C

Does not really make sense.  A minimal piece of standard C source that reads from standard input receives a stream of bytes from the system.  If the system uses UTF-8 and it produced the stream from some HID hardware, then that stream may contain UTF-8 encoded characters.  If it came from somewhere else, (eg, a network, a file) it might contain anything, which is what makes the *assumption* of a UTF-8 standard useful.

The fact that the C locale is a much more restricted char set than the UTF-8 locale is unrelated.  It's just called "the C locale", but in fact it has no more or less to do with composing C code than any other.

You can, in fact, hardcode UTF-8 characters into c-strings in the source.  Presuming the system is UTF-8, those strings will look correct when used by the resulting executable.

The "Roger Leigh" link you posted in a comment I believe refers to using an expanded set (UTF-8) *as* the C locale in a C library destined for an embedded environment, so that no other locale has to be loaded for *the system* to deal with UTF-8.

So the answer to the question, "What would break if the C locale was UTF-8 instead of ASCII?" is, I would *guess*, nothing, but outside of an embedded environment, etc. there is not much of a need to do this.  But very likely it will become the norm at some point for libraries such as GNU C (it might as well be, I think).

Comment: The behavior of various syscalls **is** influenced by the charset of the locale, for example «`isupper()` will not recognize an A-umlaut (Ä) as an uppercase letter in the default C locale.» (from http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isprint.3.html). `isprint()` is another syscall that is influenced as well by the fact that C is defined as ASCII-only.

Comment: Yes, (in theory) those are influenced by the locale, but that locale is usually UTF-8, *it is not necessarily 'C'*. In GNU, they're broken in this regard, however: http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/isupper.html Keep in mind that 100% of the fundamentals of a unix system are coded in C, so the idea that "C doesn't handle UTF-8" is well, just plain incorrect and obviously so.  If a program written in C could not deal with UTF-8, *there wouldn't be any UTF-8 on the system*.  Period.

Comment: Qv. also the POSIX isupper() page  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isupper.html "in the *current locale* of the process", not "the C locale".  This is also in the ISO standard, which refers to "in the C locale" *and* "in the current locale", usually in the form *"if the current locale is the C locale"*, etc.  Keep in mind, again, if you are on linux, GNU C's implementation of some of the ctype functions is broken.

Comment: @gioele These are library functions, not syscalls. Syscalls are calls to the kernel and are not affected by locales: locales exist purely a user level.

Comment: @goldilocks It's not quite true that "100% of the fundamentals of a unix system are coded in C". At some level, you pretty much have to have a bit of assembler, or *possibly* assembly-like C. Examples might include the boot loader loader (no typo), the actual process of task switching, and a few other similarly low-level features. On top of that, though, I agree, C (or higher-level languages) are likely used throughout the code base.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling : Point taken. That was exasperation; not sure if I did a good job of dispelling anyone's confusion about locale. :/